# ElasticSearch: Somar vários campos de um documento

Tags: elasticsearch

Preciso somar campos **diferentes** e juntá-los em um único campo no retorno do ***ElasticSearch*** (*search em modo POST*), mas só conheço a forma que **soma distintamente** cada campo, como segue:

```
"aggs" : {
    "soma1" : { "sum" : { "field" : "consulta.campo.quantidade" } },
    "soma2" : { "sum" : { "field" : "solicitacao.campo.quantidade" } },
    "soma3" : { "sum" : { "field" : "anexo.campo.quantidade" } }
}
```

Preciso **juntar** a soma das **três agregações** acima. É isso.

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thiago, voce pode simplesmente adicionar um item mais na sua agregacao que soma os resultados. So tem que tomar cuidado de usar a notacao correta do ES.

No seu exemplo para somar os 3 campos ficaria assim:

`"aggs" : {
        "consultaServicosQuantidadeAprovada" : { "sum" : { "field" : "consulta.servicos.quantidadeAprovada" } },
        "solicitacaoServicosQuantidadeAprovada" : { "sum" : { "field" : "solicitacao.servicos.quantidadeAprovada" } },
        "anexoServicosQuantidadeAprovada" : { "sum" : { "field" : "anexo.servicos.quantidadeAprovada" } },
        "totalGeral" : {
            "sum" : {
                "script" : {
                   "inline": "doc['consulta.servicos.quantidadeAprovada'] + doc['solicitacao.servicos.quantidadeAprovada'] + doc['anexo.servicos.quantidadeAprovada']"
                }
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Esse era o campo que estava precisando. Obrigado!